# How can ı create table with function?

Tags: oracle, plsql

STEP 1:

Creating a new table and adding a record to the database with the help of the procedure

• the function will take 3 parameters string ,string and number,

• The first parameter represents the name of the table, and the other two parameters represent the records to be added to the created table.

Step 2:

As seen in the screenshot below; As described above, when the function runs, a table named 'mytable' will be created in the database with the first parameter, and other parameters will be added to the created table as a record.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj2Km.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why *function*? They are supposed to return some value, not to perform DDL. Therefore, a procedure it is, using dynamic SQL as otherwise it won't work.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_test (par_table_name  IN VARCHAR2,
  2                                      par_str         IN VARCHAR2,
  3                                      par_num         IN NUMBER)
  4  IS
  5     l_cnt  NUMBER;
  6  BEGIN
  7     SELECT COUNT (*)
  8       INTO l_cnt
  9       FROM user_tables
 10      WHERE UPPER (table_name) = UPPER (par_table_name);
 11
 12     IF l_cnt = 0
 13     THEN
 14        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE   'create table '
 15                         || par_table_name
 16                         || ' as select '
 17                         || DBMS_ASSERT.enquote_literal (par_str)
 18                         || ' col_string, '
 19                         || par_num
 20                         || ' col_number from dual';
 21     ELSE
 22        raise_application_error (-20000,
 23                                 'Object with that name already exists');
 24     END IF;
 25  END;
 26  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> exec p_test('little', 'foot', 20);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from little;

COL_ COL_NUMBER
---- ----------
foot         20

SQL>
```

Comment: I agree with you suppose procedure but myteacher has been written not my fault by the way thanks lot

Comment: _"I agree with you suppose procedure but myteacher has been written not my fault"_   Perhaps you should raise this point in a discussion with your teacher.